# What is the Session ID Assigned to Incoming Calls through Dialogflow Phone Gateway?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I would like to set the context of an incoming call to Dialogflow.  The API to do that requires the session ID. When it receives an incoming call, what does the Dialogflow Call Gateway set the session ID to?  I haven't been able to find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Google Dialogflow and they provided me the answer.  The session ID can be found in the 'History' tab of the Dialogflow Console.  But Google does not currently provide an API for that.  Therefore it appears that (at least for now) you can't provide context from an external source to a session created within the Call Gateway.